# IBM MobileFirst 7.1: Retrieve the cookie when connectAs="endUser" is used

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

in our project we use stateful back-end services so we use HTTP adapter with connection `connectAS="endeUser"`. We would like to know programmatically if the cookie is already asso

Is there some(also undocumented) API that allow us to explore the cookie between the adapter and the backend service(like `WL.Server.getClientRequest().getCookies()` to explore the cookies between the client and the adapter)?

Thanks,
Iacopo

Answer (score 0):

To get the client request, which contains cookies, from the adapter you will use `WL.Server.getClientRequest()` and that will give you access to an `HttpServletRequest` object. Therefore, you have access to all it's methods including `getCookies()` for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

If you want to obtain the value of a specific cookie then you need to loop over the cookie array. For example.

```
function testProcedure() {

    var cookies = WL.Server.getClientRequest().getCookies();

    cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
        var name = cookie.getName(),
            value = cookie.getValue();

        if(name == 'myCookie') {
            // read/update cookie info
        }

        // Cookie Object
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html
    });

    return {
        cookies: cookies.length
    };
}
```